# Easier way to manage multiple branches on GitHub?

Tags: macos, git, github, github-for-mac

I have a GitHub repository with two branches `master` and `gh-pages`. I am experiencing problems when switching between branches locally. Files and folders are not being copied correctly.

Is it possible to have each branch in a separate directory locally?

i.e.

```
/Users/macuser/github/my-master/
/Users/macuser/github/my-gh-pages/
```

instead of

```
/Users/macuser/github/my/
```

Comment: How about fixing your issues with branches instead of trying to workround them? What are your problems "when switching branches" ?

Comment: @Artefact2 If I pull the latest version of a branch and then use checkout for gh-pages, some directories and files stay from the other branch. Likewise, if I switch from gh-pages to master the "img" directory gets added to the master branch. For convenience I would rather avoid having to switch branches like this. I'm also worried about loosing my changes when this happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there's no problem. Just `git clone` twice, then switch to the branch(es) you want. `push` and `pull` as needed.

Comment: I tried using `git clone git@github.com:my/project.git gh-pages` and it downloaded. How do I ensure that changes are pushed back to the correct branch?

Comment: You need to select the right branch first. `git checkout branchname`

Comment: Cool that worked, will git remember the right branch of each folder in future?

Comment: Ah, this can also be simplified to `git clone -b gh-pages git@github.com:my/project.git gh-pages`. Thanks for helping me find this much appreciated. This should be a lot easier than what I was doing before!

Comment: No problem. Good luck and happy developing.